# Affinity isolated peptide

Tags: biochemistry

What is affinity isolated peptides??
(I have not studied biology since last 8 years and now I am going through it because I need it for my research. So if someone can describe it in simple language it would be very helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A peptide or protein can be purified by affinity chromatography. The principle is that the peptide has some substrate to which it will bind, retarding its progress through the column compared to the rest of the peptide population. A couple of typical examples are:

- Using a His6 tag put on recombinant molecules, IIRC it binds to Ni2+ trapped in the chromatographic resin and is eluted with a chelator like EDTA.
- Immunoaffinity chromatography, where you have a population of antibodies on the chromatographic resin which are specific to the protein that you want to purify (or alternatively having the immunogen bound to the resin so that you can purify the antibodies against it)

Mighty Wikipedia has a link about affinity chromatography [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_chromatography).

Comment: so its basically purification or extraction of peptide from a mixture using affinity chromatography...

Comment: Affinity isolated peptides/proteins are an output/product of affinity chromatography.